# Monoidal equivalences

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Consider the strict 2-category of monoidal categories with (lax) monoidal functors as 1-morphisms. There is a general notion of adjunctions and (adjoint) equivalences in (strict) 2-categories. Call these monoidal adjunctions resp. monoidal equivalences in our special case.

Let $L\vdash R$ be a monoidal equivalence. Is it true that $L$ and $R$ are *strong* monoidal? Note that there is an oplax structure on $F$ given by
$$L(X\otimes Y)\longrightarrow L(RLX\otimes RLY)\longrightarrow LR(LX\otimes LY)\longrightarrow LX\otimes LY$$
(in fact, this only requires $L$ to be monoidally left adjoint to $R$), and similarly for $R$.

But I am not able to prove that this is inverse to the lax structure morphism of $L$. Is it even true?

Comment: 1) You mean that $F,G$ are strong monoidal, right? 2) I assume that you already know that $F,G$ is part of a monoidal adjunction. Have you tried to use that unit and counit are monoidal transformations?

Comment: 1) Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed true that a monoidal adjunction suffices, i.e. the left adjoint of a lax monoidal adjunction is necessarily strong. It seems this also follows from a more general principle called doctrinal adjunction invented by Kelly, but a direct verification is also possible. The diagram pasting goes as follows:
[image: Diagram monoidal adjunction]
Here $\varphi$ denotes both $LX\otimes LY\longrightarrow L(X\otimes Y)$ and $RX\otimes RY\longrightarrow R(X\otimes Y)$.

Comment: This would be an "answer" if you share with us the details that you have worked out. :)

Comment: @Heinrich Here you go.

Comment: Thank you. Nice diagram :)